# Generate two IEnumerables and combining them

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable, graph-theory

I had really hard time writing the title, I am not sure if it's good enough.

I am making a routing application. I am using Entity Framework. Because my map is an undirected graph, I need to retrieve the edges twice (A->B, B->A) from the database, where they are stored only as (A->B).

So far, I had this:

```
public IList<Edge> GetBatteryCenterEdges(string name)
{
    var query =
        from edges in context.Edge
        where (edges.BatteryStation.name.Equals(name) || edges.BatteryStation1.name.Equals(name))
        select edges;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

But that would return only A->B.

I must notice I am fairly new into C# and LINQ.

I tried doing:

```
IEnumerable<Edge> test = query.Select(x => new Edge { BatteryStation = x.BatteryStation1, BatteryStation1 = x.BatteryStation });
```

(`BatteryStation` and `BatteryStation1` are basically the vertices)

Then I tried to do

`query.Union(test)`

But that wouldn't return any of the reversed `Edge`s.

So I tried returning the `test` and it would result in:

`The entity or complex type 'CarBatteryModel.Edge' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

How can I reverse those `Edge` objects from the database in the best way possible?

My classes:

`Edge` comes from ET:

```
public partial class Edge
{
    public virtual BatteryStation BatteryStation { get; set; }
    public virtual BatteryStation BatteryStation1 { get; set; }
}
```

`BatteryCenter` inherits from the `BatteryStation` which comes from ET:

```
public class BatteryCenter : BatteryStation
{
    public IList<Edge> Edgelist;

    public BatteryCenter()
    {
        Edgelist = new List<Edge>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual data structure you want to store the so-called `(A->B, B->A)`? Looks like it's a `List<Tuple<Edge,Edge>>`?

Comment: The way I have done it I have `List<Edge>` in each `BatteryStation`. `Edge` consists of two `BatteryStation` objects - `BatteryStation` and `BatteryStation1`

Comment: As I thought, one edge is just `A->B` or `B->A` so how could you store both with just an `Edge`? BTW, I know we can always derive the other edge from the edge `A->B`, so your requirement is still unclear, it depends on the actual data structure you want.

Comment: I do not store them with just an edge, I store both ways `A->B` and `B->A` with two `Edge` objects. When I retrieve them from the database, they only come as `A->B` so I need to re-loop the `query` and make a copy of it, just with all the edges turned around (I should end up with `list1` with edges `A->B` and `list2` with edges `B->A` and then merge them. `list1` is the one which comes from the DB

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of Edge containing all the `A->B` and the `B->A`? Do you care about the order? I mean all the `A->B`s are filled into the list first then all the `B->A`s are filled, or it can be in any order?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I already have the `A->B` and I want the same list but `B->A` done in a better way than using a loop (I did that, but I believe there is a smarter solution)

Comment: If you want it ordered like this: `A1->B1`, `A2->B2`, .... `B1->A1`, `B2->A2`..., I think we have to order after merging all together and so there must be some way to compare 2 edges. If you can satisfy with this order `A1->B1`, `B1->A1`, `A2->B2`, `B2->A2`, ... I think there is an easy solution (without needing any more ordering step).

Comment: Because I am using this method for a certain vertex (`BatteryStation`) I do not care about the order, all I care is all `A->B` goes to `B->A` (`A1->B1` goes to `B1->A1`, etc, etc). Can you hit me up with the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use method syntax for this:

```
var query = context.Edge.Where(edge=>edge.BatteryStation.name.Equals(name) ||
                                     edge.BatteryStation1.name.Equals(name))
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .SelectMany(edge => new []{ edge,
                                            new Edge{
                                             BatteryStation = edge.BatteryStation1,
                                             BatteryStation1 = edge.BatteryStation
                                            }
                               });
return query.ToList();
```

**Update**:

Try bulding `Expression tree`:

```
var query = context.Edge.Where(edge=>edge.BatteryStation.name.Equals(name) ||
                                     edge.BatteryStation1.name.Equals(name));
var edgeParam = Expression.Param(typeof(Edge),"edge");
var edgeBA = Expression.New(typeof(Edge));
var bind1 = Expression.Bind(typeof(Edge).GetProperty("BatteryStation"),
                            Expression.Property(edgeParam, "BatteryStation1"));
var bind2 = Expression.Bind(typeof(Edge).GetProperty("BatteryStation1"),
                            Expression.Property(edgeParam, "BatteryStation"));
var edgeBAInit = Expression.MemberInit(edgeBA, bind1, bind2);
var edgeArray = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(Edge),edgeParam, edgeBAInit);
var selectManyLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Edge,IEnumerable<Edge>>>(
                                  edgeArray, edgeParam);
return query.SelectMany(selectManyLambda).ToList();
```

Comment: That would result in this error: `The entity or complex type 'CarBatteryModel.Edge' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.` which I already managed to get when I was trying to do stuff on my own.

Comment: @Nikola maybe you have to use `AsEnumerable` before `SelectMany`, it of course processes things on client side.

Comment: @Nikola could you try using the solution I posted in the **Update**? We can build some *Expression tree* and process everything on the server side. Thanks!